# Does Tokina SD 70 - 210 1:4-5.6 work with Nikon D40?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d40, tokina

I recently got Tokina SD 70-210 1:4-5.6 lens from ebay however it doesn't fit on Nikon D40. Screen shows **Lens not attached**.

This lens came with Nikon N2020 and is fully functional with it.

Please share some information whether this lens can mount on Nikon D40.

Answer (score 1):

When you say it doesn't fit, it does mount, doesn't it?  Your N2020 will have the same mount as the D40.  Does it rotate and click when you try to mount it?

Assuming it does, there are two things to try:

- clean the contacts on both the lens and the camera (with a dry cloth, or if they're really dirty with a pencil eraser, taking care to not get bits inside your camera)
- make sure the lens aperture is locked at the minimum (f/32 I think)

I don't know which model of the 70-210 you have, but my guess it the camera won't meter, so you'll have to use manual mode.

Comment: Does it rotate and click when you try to mount it? Yes it does. The contacts on both the lens and the camera are clean. I have not tried by keeping lens aperture (f/32). Also please advice how to check which model of the 70-210 I have. It shows Tokina SD 70-210 1:4-5.6

Comment: Thank you MikeW for your suggestion. My D40 was on A mode hence that error. I changed it to M mode. Now its working fine.